Eigenvalues and eigenvectors of certain rank two Hermitian matrix
Let $n\geq 2$ and  $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ such that
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & x^*\\
x & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
for some $x\in\mathbb{C}^{n-1}\backslash\{0\}$. Is there an explicit form for the eigenvectors and/or the eigenvalues of $A$?

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

Optimistically, the eigenvectors are of the form $$v_{a,y} := \begin{bmatrix} a \\ y \end{bmatrix}$$ with $a \in \mathbb{C}$ and $y \in \mathbb{C}^{n-1}$. If $y \in x^{\perp}$, we see that $v_{0,y} \in \ker(A)$. This gives us $n-2$ independent eigenvectors. Maybe the remaining eigenvectors of the form $v_{a,x}$. Let's check: $$Av_{a,x}  = \lambda v_{a,x} \iff ax = \lambda x \ \text{ and } \ \lambda a = x^*x \iff \lambda = a \ \text{ and } a^2 = x^*x.$$ So $v_{\|x\|,x}$ and $v_{-\|x\|,x}$ are eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalues $\|x\|$ and $-\|x\|$.

Consider the Hermitian matrix
$$H(a,b,c)=\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
a&\overline{b_1}&\overline{b_2}&\ldots&\overline{b_n}\\
b_1&c_1&0&\ldots&0\\b_2&0&c_2&\ldots&0\\\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots\\
b_n&0&\ldots&\ldots&c_n
\end{array}\right]$$ By induction we have $$\det H(a,b,c)=c_1c_2\ldots c_n\left(a-\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\|b_i\|^2}{c_i}\right).$$ With this formula you can easily compute the eigenvalues of the matrix $H(0,b,0)$  and find its eigenvectors.
